# main i386 Packages

Tags: 32-bit

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 and it seems that these packages are not installed. How can I install them as I need them for an application ?

Err http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages
  404  Not Found

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you added the PPA using a wrong procedure.  Uninstall the last PPA you installed by using the reverse procedure you used to install it and add it again using:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:TheUser/TheNameOfThePPA
sudo apt-get update
```

and only then do a:

```
sudo apt-get install ThePackageName
```

And the above commands would have been *even more helpful* if you would have given:

- the name of the package instead of "these"
- the procedure you used to install the package